# How to select entire column data of 2 rows using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Let me explain what actually I want to do.I am storing user's information in mysql table named "students_data". Here, now I just want to print those names in the table below except the user who logged in.Suppose I haven total 5 users list including me on table with their First name , last name and others detail.
Below the h2 tag in table I want to print those names that are on table only the First name and last name, obviously excluding me.

```
<?php
$serverName="localhost";  
$userName="samsung";  
$password="8198982039";  
$dataBase="students_record";  
$conn=mysqli_connect($serverName,$userName,$password,$dataBase);  
$sql= "SELECT First_Name FROM students_data";  
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);  
$cols=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH);  
?>  

<html>  
<head>  
    <title></title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" >  
    <style>  
    </style>  
</head>  
<body>
<div class="container">  
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>  
<div class="col-sm-4" >  
    <h2>Friends You may know</h2>  
    <table class="table table-striped">  
        <tr>  
            <td><?php?></td>  
        </tr>  
    </table>  
</div>  
<div class="col-sm-4" >  
    <h2>Your status</h2>  
</div>  
</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: can you tell how's you get logged-in user id?

Comment: Actually , I want to print all those list(first name & last name) in the table except me inside the td tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please adjust variables accordingly, and it will work for you. thanks:-

```
<?php
$serverName="localhost";  
$userName="samsung";  
$password="8198982039";  
$dataBase="students_record";  
$logged_in_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; // i assume that you store logged-in user in in session variable having name user_id
$conn=mysqli_connect($serverName,$userName,$password,$dataBase);  
$sql= "SELECT First_Name,Last_name FROM students_data where id !='".$logged_in_user_id.""; // get all user except logged in user
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);  

$user_data = array();
$i = 0;
while($cols=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result,MYSQLI_BOTH);) {
    $user_data[$i]['first_name'] = $cols['First_Name'];// get first name
    $user_data[$i]['last_name'] = $cols['Last_Name'];   // get last name
}
?>  

<html>  
<head>  
    <title></title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" >  
    <style>  
    </style>  
</head>  
<body>
<div class="container">  
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>  
<div class="col-sm-4" >  
    <h2>Friends You may know</h2>  
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <?php foreach ($user_data as $user){//iterate that user data array?> 
        <tr>  
            <td><?php echo $user['first_name'];?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $user['last_name']?></td>  
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>      
    </table>  
</div>  
<div class="col-sm-4" >  
    <h2>Your status</h2>  
</div>  
</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: As I said already, I want to exclude just my details from table and wanted to include all others users in the table and I am not using session.

Comment: At least you can do that much. Just pass your id to query and get the desire result. you will exclude and others will come. how you will pass your id it's up to you. I think you are able to do that

Answer (score 0):

if you are using session

```
$idtoexclude = $_SESSION['onlineuserid'];
$sql= "SELECT * FROM students_data WHERE NOT id = '$idtoexclude'";
```

Comment: I am doing all these without session. And I want to print first name and last name  of every users in table except me. Hope you became clear with problem.

Comment: what are you using then to get online user id?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I came up with right solution now.